# What does the word 'dispropriate' mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The RSHT lawsuit highlights the **dispropriate** impact of abusive for-profit school practices on poor and minority students.

source:https://www.studentloanborrowerassistance.org/reverse-redlining-discrimination-and-for-profit-education/#:~:text=Redlining%20is%20the%20practice%20of,protected%20classes%20for%20predatory%20lending.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "dispropriate" is simply an error.
Collins dictionary says "dispropriate" is an obsolete term meaning "to deprive of ownership." In that use, it is a verb, and it doesn't have a sense as an adjective.

It should have been `disproportionate`, to fit the meaning of the sentence.

[American Heritage Dictionary "disproportionate"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=disproportionate)
"Out of proportion, as in size, shape, or amount."

The meaning is that the effect of redlining falls excessively on poor and minority students.